# Cummulative sum in Excel with statment

Tags: excel, sum

I have a trouble!
For example:
I have one column "A" with values: 0, 1, 1, 1, 0 etc.
And in the "B" column must contain cummulative sum of zeroes. If there will be zero the cummulative sum resets its value.
*For example:* 
A: *0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1 etc.*
 
B: *0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2 etc.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IN **B1** enter:

```
=A1
```

In **B2** enter:

```
=IF(A2=0,0,A2+B1)
```

and copy down